# Memory leak, when i copy data from one treeStore into another ext js 4.1

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, extjs

I have two extjs treeStores, one is temp, another is working treeStore, which data interprets by treePanel. Code:

```
var treeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore',{
root: {
childrens:[],
expanded: true,
text: 'Services'
}
 });
  var tempStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore',{
    autoload: false,
    proxy:{
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'server.jsp',
      reader: {
          type:'json'
      }
    },
    clearOnLoad: true,
  listeners:{
    load:{
        fn: afterload
    }
    }   
  });
  tempStore.load();

  function afterload(store)
  {
 var rootTree = treeStore.getRootNode();
 var copyChilds = Ext.clone(store.getRootNode().childNodes);
 if(rootTree.hasChildNodes())
 {
 rootTree.removeAll(false);
 }
 for(var i=0;i<copyChilds.length;i++)
 {
 rootTree.appendChild(copyChilds[i]);
 }
}
```

When tempStore.load method invoked, i'll send query on server, get data and then put it on another treeStore.p> 
  The tempStore reload every 3 seconds using TaskRunner:

```
var taskTree = {
        run: reloadTree,
    interval:3000 // 1 second
       }
 var runReloadTreePanel = Ext.create("Ext.util.TaskRunner");
```

I have checkbox, when i change the state of it into true the runner start works:

```
var checkbox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Checkbox',{
       boxLabel: 'Refresh',
       listeners :{
           change: {
                fn: changeCheckBoxState
            }
        }
});
    function changeCheckBoxState(field,newValue,oldValue) 
         {
      if(newValue)
    {
            runReloadTreePanel.start(taskTree);
    }
      else
    {
    runReloadTreePanel.stop(taskTree);
    }
         }
```

**The problem**:

After 2-3 minutes of start memory begin grows(3-4MB every 10seconds), because of method afterload content, which is copy data. Is it bug or i do something wrong?? Maybe the function removeAll(false) didn't remove all child data of treeStore root node? I used a lot of variants - clean dom model elements using Ext.select(..) + innerHtml, try to remove the records one by one using remove(..), but the memory grows.
   My treepanel interprets all good, without unnecessary data.
Any ideas? Sorry if my english isn't good.(

Comment: difficult to say whats going on, but do make sure not to create global vars - they are never garbage collected.  if you are using var X = y make sure that X is local to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried to change content of function load to this:

```
function load(store)
{
var childs = Ext.clone(store.getRootNode().childNodes);
Ext.select('div#treepanel-1032-body div table tbody tr[class^="x-grid-row"]').remove();
treepanel.setRootNode({
 text: "Services",
 expanded: true,
 children: childs
});
```

I removed dom model object directly, removed from config properties of treepanel store, and set every 3 sec new root, but the memory grows, especially in IE. Any advices?